# Conflict in wildcard query and spellchecker in solr search

Tags: solr, wildcard, spell-checking

Using solr search when i search for rin* it run wildcard query and i get the result for ring but when i search for Rin* it run spellchecker and then gives the result for ring.
why so ?? please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using wildcard searches, the standard query tokenizer chain is bypassed by design.

To quote [AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers)

> On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the search word